# Stopping consumers from consuming messages from queue

Tags: activemq-classic

I am starting with ActiveMQ and I have a usecase. i have n producers sending messages into a Queue Q1. I want to stop the delivery of messages (i.e. i do not want consumers to consume those messages). I want to store the messages for sometime without those being consumed.

I was looking at ways this can be achieved. These two things came into my mind based on what i browsed through.

- Using Mirrored queues, so that I can wiretap the messages and save into a virtual queue.
- Possibly stop consumers from doing a PULL on the queue.
- Another dirty way of doing this is by making consumers not send ack messages once its consumed a message from the queue.

We are currently not happy with either of these.

Any other way you can suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want message delivery to be delayed you can use the [scheduler](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html) feature of ActiveMQ to delay delivery until a set time or a fixed delay etc.

Other strategies might also work but it really up to you to design something that fits your use case.  You can try to use Apache [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) to define a route that implements the logic of your use case to either dispatch a message to a Queue or send it to the scheduler for delayed processing.  It all really depends on your use case and requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way we could just start the consumer in stopped state. i saw one of the SO question where you also want to do something like this.

Comment: You can stop the connection, then the consumers are stopped as well.